# How to verify that a SC implements an interface. Considering the parameters that are returned

Tags: erc165

The Ethereum ecosystem has an ERC165 standard that allows you to check whether a contract implements an interface. But this standard is based only on the method name and input params and not return params. For example:

```
interface Bar {
    function MethodFoo(uint256) string
}
```

and

```
interface Bar {
     function MethodFoo(uint256) uint256
}
```

For ERC165, these are two identical interfaces because the return values were not included in the methodId. But I, as a client, want to be sure that I will get the type of data I expect, but the ERC165 standard does not allow this

Comment: Unfortunately the return type isn't part of a function signature. In both cases the signature will be the same. You could write your own EIP with return types, but it is unlikely that it will be considered. At least I haven't seen many people complain about not having the return type.